# Set Theory and difference and complement rules

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Consider the following to list the elements in the sets

1. $\mathbb{Z} ∩ (\mathbb{Z} \setminus \mathbb{Q})$
2. $\neg\{x \in \mathbb{Z} : x^2 > 25\}$

I am learning about sets and have come across some videos and would like some help with the above.

On 1 since the Natural numbers are a subset of the rational numbers wouldn't that mean that $\mathbb{N}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is an empty set? Therefore, the intersection of the integers with the empty set is empty.

On the second one everything has a line on top which I believe is the complement or the negation. If that is true then would that be all the elements $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^2 \le 25$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> since the Natural numbers are a subset of the irrational numbers

You must be thinking of the rationals. All natural numbers are rational, and hence $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$.

> that mean that N-Q is an empty set?

Correct. The operation $\mathbb{N} - \mathbb{Q}$ takes every rational number that lies in $\mathbb{N}$, and removes it. But since all of the elements of $\mathbb{N}$ ***are*** rational, you are left with the empty set.

> Therefore, the intersection of the integers with the empty set is empty.

Correct.

> On the second one everything has a line on top which I believe is the complement or the negation. If that is true then would that be all the elements in x part of Z such that x^2 <= 25?

Depends on context. The complement is always taken with respect to some "universal set".

Suppose I want to find $\overline{\{1\}}$. What does this mean? Well, it's all of the elements that aren't $1$. ... Okay, but what are those elements?

For instance, if my "universe" is $\mathbb{Z}$, then we would say $\overline{\{1\}}=\{\cdots,-3,-2,-1,0,2,3,4,\cdots\}$, i.e. $\mathbb{Z} - \{1\}$.

On the other hand, if my universe were $\mathbb{R}$, then $\overline{\{1\}} = (-\infty,1) \cup (1,\infty) = \mathbb{R} - \{1\}$. This certainly contains a lot more elements than the previous, and more exotic non-integers like $\pi$.

If we are supposed to take as given your universal set as $\mathbb{Z}$, then yes your characterization is correct.

Comment: Amazing explanation. So as a rule would be if you subtract a subset from its set then it gives out an empty set.

Comment: Yes - in general, if $A \subseteq B$, then $A - B = \varnothing$.